# Using repeated measures change/trend as a predictor variable

Tags: r, repeated-measures, regression-coefficients, trend, pre-post-comparison

I have repeated measures of `happiness` for a sample of participants, and a single measure of `satisfaction` for each of the participants.

I want to predict `satisfaction` from the repeated measures of `happiness`. To do so, I want to create a new variable, called `happiness.change`, which measures the degree of change/trend in `happiness` from the first measurement to the last, for each participant (for example, a negative `happiness.change` if there is a decrease in `happiness` over time). Then I want to predict `satisfaction` from `happiness.change`.

Below (using R) is an excerpt from my data (a sample of 9 participants):

```
ids <- c(rep(seq(1:5), each = 2), rep(6:9, each = 5))
time <- c(rep(1:2, 5), rep(1:5, 4))
happiness <- c(0.80,0.00,0.75,0.00,0.80,0.00,2.75,2.50,0.40,0.20,
               3.80,0.40,0.00,0.20,3.40,3.00,2.60,3.40,3.80,0.00,
               3.60,3.60,0.20,0.40,1.00,0.40,0.20,1.20,1.20,0.00)
satisfaction <- c(6,6,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,7,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(ids, time, happiness, satisfaction),
                         nrow = 30,
                         ncol = 4,
                         dimnames = list(c(),c("id", "time",
                                               "happiness", "satisfaction"))))
print(data)

#    id time happiness satisfaction
# 1   1    1      0.80            6
# 2   1    2      0.00            6
# 3   2    1      0.75            2
# 4   2    2      0.00            2
# 5   3    1      0.80            3
# 6   3    2      0.00            3
# 7   4    1      2.75            2
# 8   4    2      2.50            2
# 9   5    1      0.40            2
# 10  5    2      0.20            2
# 11  6    1      3.80            5
# 12  6    2      0.40            5
# 13  6    3      0.00            5
# 14  6    4      0.20            5
# 15  6    5      3.40            5
# 16  7    1      3.00            7
# 17  7    2      2.60            7
# 18  7    3      3.40            7
# 19  7    4      3.80            7
# 20  7    5      0.00            7
# 21  8    1      3.60            1
# 22  8    2      3.60            1
# 23  8    3      0.20            1
# 24  8    4      0.40            1
# 25  8    5      1.00            1
# 26  9    1      0.40            2
# 27  9    2      0.20            2
# 28  9    3      1.20            2
# 29  9    4      1.20            2
# 30  9    5      0.00            2
```

To create `happiness.change` I was advised to use the coefficients produced by either of these equations:

```
require(lme4)
model1 <- lmer(happiness ~ time + (time | id), data = data)

require(nlme)
model2 <- lme(happiness ~ time, random = ~1 + time | id, data = data)
```

For example, running `coef(model1)` produces the following coefficients (column `time`):

```
# $id
#   (Intercept)        time
# 1   0.9936158 -0.05991770
# 2   0.9739595 -0.05674569
# 3   0.9936158 -0.05991770
# 4   2.5539086 -0.31170766
# 5   0.8998610 -0.04478815
# 6   2.0446747 -0.22953078
# 7   3.2906564 -0.43059926
# 8   2.7120530 -0.33722798
# 9   1.0027053 -0.06138450
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "coef.mer"
```

And then connecting between `satisfaction` and the coefficients:

```
coefs1 <- as.data.frame(unlist(coef(model1))[10:18])
satisfactionData <- reshape(data,
                            direction = "wide",
                            idvar = "id",
                            timevar = "time")[c(1,3)]
newData <- cbind(satisfactionData, coefs1)
colnames(newData) <- c("id", "satisfaction", "happiness.change")
print(newData)

#    id satisfaction happiness.change
# 1   1            6      -0.05991770
# 3   2            2      -0.05674569
# 5   3            3      -0.05991770
# 7   4            2      -0.31170766
# 9   5            2      -0.04478815
# 11  6            5      -0.22953078
# 16  7            7      -0.43059926
# 21  8            1      -0.33722798
# 26  9            2      -0.06138450
```

---

**I have several questions:**

1. Running `model2` generates the following error:

   ```
   Error in lme.formula(happiness ~ time, random = ~1 + time | id, data = data) : 
     nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
     message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)
   ```

   I don't remember where, but I read that running `lme(happiness ~ time, random = ~1 + time | id, control = list(opt = "optim"), data = data)` bypasses this error, and indeed it does. But what exactly does it do? Do the coefficients produced by using this model still represent the change in `happiness` over time?
2. Running `model2` (with `control = list(opt = "optim")`) produces slightly (*very* slightly) different coefficients than `model1`; why? What is the difference between the models?
3. What would be the suitable method for testing the relationship between `happiness.change` and `satisfaction`? I tried `cor.test(newData$satisfaction, newData$happiness.change)`, which produced the following results, but I'm not sure how to interpret them (they are significant in the complete data set):

   ```
       Pearson's product-moment correlation

   data:  newData$satisfaction and newData$happiness.change
   t = -0.72735, df = 7, p-value = 0.4906
   alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
   95 percent confidence interval:
    -0.7901064  0.4843018
   sample estimates:
          cor 
   -0.2650786
   ```
4. As you can see, `model1` produces negative coefficients for all the participants (`model2` as well). Even for participants whose change over time is purely positive (for example, a participant with 2 `happiness` measures: `time1 = 0` and `time2 = 0.8`; no such example in the sample above, but it is in my data).

   This may be a problem, because I want to be able to distinguish between participants whose change in `happiness` is positive (`happiness` increases over time) and participants whose change in `happiness` is negative (`happiness` decreases over time); and then see whether there's a difference between these participants in their relationship between `happiness.change` and `satisfaction`.

   So my question is this: Is it statistically "legit" to divide my participants beforehand into groups based on their "raw" change in `happiness` (for example, I would label a participant with `time1 = 0` and `time2 = 0.8` as having a positive change), and then model the coefficient for these groups separately?

   However, creating sub-groups this way may be difficult with participants with more than 2 measures of `happiness`, which brings me to my final question:
5. If I understand correctly, `model1` and `model2` assume there is a linear change over time. However, I checked the whole sample (424 participants), and a cubic model (`happiness ~ time`) actually explains more of the variance in `happiness`. So I suppose a cubic change over time is more appropriate. How can I create a new variable reflecting such a change in `happiness` over time?

I realize this is quite long and these are a lot of questions, and so any help will be greatly appreciated. If anyone can answer even one of these questions, I will be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to do this as a structural equation model - search for 'sequelae of change'.

Comment: Thank you. I'm fairly new to this. Could you please elaborate? I did some searching but SEM is a massive subject. And the information I found on 'sequelae of change' was way over my head. What do you think this will help me with? Are there any tutorials on this subject for R or SPSS? Or any other software?

Comment: It's an extension of growth curve modeling. There are examples in R (using the package lavaan). If you can run a growth model, you should be able to get the same result as the lme above. Then you add an outcome. I'll try to write an answer later.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I'll check growth curve modeling and lavaan.